# Bitmap Index join

Tags: java, database, join, bitmap

I am working on a bitmap index implementation using java. I have two files
which have different number of tuples.(Both files are of different size)
Both the files have the same structure with department id as the common field. 
I need to perform a join on the tuples in the two fields on department id.
I have created a matrix with department ids as rows and line numbers as column 
index. If the department id is there for a particular line number i assign one 
otherwise its set to 0.

```
The output for the first file looks like:
Unique department ids are :

112
355
010
230

Default

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

row :>>0column :>>0
row :>>1column :>>1
row :>>2column :>>2
row :>>1column :>>3
row :>>3column :>>4
row :>>1column :>>5
row :>>0column :>>6
Time Taken : 47ms
Memory Taken (in bytes): 436480.0 bytes
Memory Taken (in MB): 0.416259765625 MB
Total number of columns =7
Total number of rows =4
{0=112, 1=355, 2=010, 3=230}
The new array is :::::
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 

The output for the second file :
Free memory>>63.083763

Unique department ids are :
333
355
989
010
230

default 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
row :>>3column :>>0
row :>>0column :>>1
row :>>4column :>>2
row :>>2column :>>3
row :>>1column :>>4
Time Taken : 46ms
Memory Taken (in bytes): 436456.0 bytes
Memory Taken (in MB): 0.41623687744140625 MB
Total number of columns =5
Total number of rows =5
{0=333, 1=355, 2=989, 3=010, 4=230}
The new array is :::::
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
```

I want to perform a join operation between the two matrix but since both the files are of different vector length I am confused how should i do this